# Обработка сигналов

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!Я только учусь программировать на си. Сегодня начал разбираться с сигналами. Помогите,пожалуйста, решить задачу. Надо чтобы программа при попытке завершить её первые 25 раз писала что-нибудь, а на 26 раз завершилась. 
Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int sq=0;

void hdl(int n){
if(sq<25){
    printf("press it again\n");
    sq++;
}
exit(1);
}

int main(){
char cku;
cku=getchar();
signal(SIGINT,&hdl);
while(1){
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
}
```

Никак не получается заставить её работать.....

Comment: У вас return 0 в цикле завершает main а следовательно и программу. Его стоит убрать а sleep можно и на большее время ставить.

Comment: Тогда программа вообще не завершается. А переменная sq вообще никак не меняется

Comment: А вы из цикла return все таки уберите, а в обработчике сигнала внутрь if сразу после sq++ добавьте return. А то у вас обработчик то сейчас завершает программу всегда

Comment: Спасибо.Все заработало